# ArgumentException thrown When GroupJoin is applied on a DbSet as a first join and NOT when applied as a second or later

Tags: entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, ef-core-6.0

**1. Exception Case:**
LINQ: Here, I have a query which is doing a GroupJoin on an DbSet and then adding other inner joins.
**Repository.ConvertToBigIntTable** -> This is an output of a call to a Table-Valued function which returns an IQueryable (T is a Keyless entity having a **long Id** field)

```cs
private IQueryable<IDocumentTypePermission> GetDocumentTypePermissionsTest<T>(IQueryable<T> entitySet) where T : class, IDocumentType
{
    var userGroupIds = RunComponent(GetActiveUserGroupsOfCurrentUser.New(new GetActiveUserGroupsOfCurrentUserParam() { CurrentUserId = CurrentUserId })).UserGroupIds;
    return (from documentType in entitySet
            join userGroupId in Repository.ConvertToBigIntTable(userGroupIds, "userGroupId")
            on documentType.Id equals userGroupId.Id into UserGroupIds
            from userGroupId in UserGroupIds.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join documentTypePermission in Repository.DocumentTypePermissions
            on documentType.Id equals documentTypePermission.DocumentTypeId
            join userSelectionParam in Repository.UserSelectionParams
            on documentTypePermission.UserSelectionId equals userSelectionParam.Id

            
            where documentTypePermission.IsActive && ((userSelectionParam.UserGroupId != null && userGroupId.Id != null)
                                                        || (userSelectionParam.UserId != null && userSelectionParam.UserId == CurrentUserId))
            select documentTypePermission);
}
```

```cs
DbSet<EDocumentType>()
    .GroupJoin(
        inner: BananaContext.ConvertCSVToBigIntTable(
            List: <>c__DisplayClass958_0.List, 
            Delim: <>c__DisplayClass958_0.Delim), 
        outerKeySelector: documentType => documentType.Id, 
        innerKeySelector: userGroupId => userGroupId.Id, 
        resultSelector: (documentType, UserGroupIds) => new { 
            documentType = documentType, 
            UserGroupIds = UserGroupIds
         })
    .SelectMany(
        collectionSelector: <>h__TransparentIdentifier0 => <>h__TransparentIdentifier0.UserGroupIds
            .DefaultIfEmpty(), 
        resultSelector: (<>h__TransparentIdentifier0, userGroupId) => new { 
            <>h__TransparentIdentifier0 = <>h__TransparentIdentifier0, 
            userGroupId = userGroupId
         })
    .Join(
        inner: DbSet<EDocumentTypePermission>(), 
        outerKeySelector: <>h__TransparentIdentifier1 => (long?)<>h__TransparentIdentifier1.<>h__TransparentIdentifier0.documentType.Id, 
        innerKeySelector: documentTypePermission => documentTypePermission.DocumentTypeId, 
        resultSelector: (<>h__TransparentIdentifier1, documentTypePermission) => new { 
            <>h__TransparentIdentifier1 = <>h__TransparentIdentifier1, 
            documentTypePermission = documentTypePermission
         })
    .Join(
        inner: DbSet<EUserSelectionParam>(), 
        outerKeySelector: <>h__TransparentIdentifier2 => <>h__TransparentIdentifier2.documentTypePermission.UserSelectionId, 
        innerKeySelector: userSelectionParam => (long?)userSelectionParam.Id, 
        resultSelector: (<>h__TransparentIdentifier2, userSelectionParam) => new { 
            <>h__TransparentIdentifier2 = <>h__TransparentIdentifier2, 
            userSelectionParam = userSelectionParam
         })
    .Where(<>h__TransparentIdentifier3 => <>h__TransparentIdentifier3.<>h__TransparentIdentifier2.documentTypePermission.IsActive && <>h__TransparentIdentifier3.userSelectionParam.UserGroupId != null && (long?)<>h__TransparentIdentifier3.<>h__TransparentIdentifier2.<>h__TransparentIdentifier1.userGroupId.Id != null || <>h__TransparentIdentifier3.userSelectionParam.UserId != null && <>h__TransparentIdentifier3.userSelectionParam.UserId == (long?)AbstractDomainBehavior.CurrentUserId)
    .Select(<>h__TransparentIdentifier3 => <>h__TransparentIdentifier3.<>h__TransparentIdentifier2.documentTypePermission)
```

**Exception:**

```
Expression of type 'System.Func`2[Lw.Domain.IDocumentType,System.Int64]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Lw.Domain.EDocumentType,System.Int64]]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType290`2[<>f__AnonymousType289`2[Lw.Domain.IDocumentType,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Lw.Sys.Repository.ITableValueFunctionResult]],Lw.Sys.Repository.ITableValueFunctionResult]] LeftJoin[EDocumentType,ITableValueFunctionResult,Int64,<>f__AnonymousType290`2](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Lw.Domain.EDocumentType], System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Lw.Sys.Repository.ITableValueFunctionResult], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Lw.Domain.EDocumentType,System.Int64]], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Lw.Sys.Repository.ITableValueFunctionResult,System.Int64]], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[Lw.Domain.EDocumentType,Lw.Sys.Repository.ITableValueFunctionResult,<>f__AnonymousType290`2[<>f__AnonymousType289`2[Lw.Domain.IDocumentType,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Lw.Sys.Repository.ITableValueFunctionResult]],Lw.Sys.Repository.ITableValueFunctionResult]]])' (Parameter 'arg2')
```

Stack Trace:

```
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionUtils.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arguments, ParameterInfo pi, String methodParamName, String argumentParamName, Int32 index)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(MethodInfo method, Expression arg0, Expression arg1, Expression arg2, Expression arg3, Expression arg4)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryableMethodNormalizingExpressionVisitor.TryFlattenGroupJoinSelectMany(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionVisitorUtils.VisitArguments(ExpressionVisitor visitor, IArgumentProvider nodes)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryableMethodNormalizingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionVisitorUtils.VisitArguments(ExpressionVisitor visitor, IArgumentProvider nodes)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryableMethodNormalizingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionVisitorUtils.VisitArguments(ExpressionVisitor visitor, IArgumentProvider nodes)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryableMethodNormalizingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionVisitorUtils.VisitArguments(ExpressionVisitor visitor, IArgumentProvider nodes)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryableMethodNormalizingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryTranslationPreprocessor.NormalizeQueryableMethod(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryTranslationPreprocessor.NormalizeQueryableMethod(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryTranslationPreprocessor.Process(Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()
```

***NOTE: Interestingly trying to do a very similar operation on LinqPad7 seems to work:***
[image]

**2. Working Case**
LINQ: Here, I have a query which is performing inner joins on few DbSets and then applying GroupJoin on one of the DbSet.
**Repository.ConvertToBigIntTable** -> This is an output of a call to a Table-Valued function which returns an IQueryable (T is a Keyless entity having a **long Id** field)

```cs
private IQueryable<IDocumentTypePermission> GetDocumentTypePermissions<T>(IQueryable<T> entitySet) where T : class, IDocumentType
{
    var userGroupIds = RunComponent(GetActiveUserGroupsOfCurrentUser.New(new GetActiveUserGroupsOfCurrentUserParam() { CurrentUserId = CurrentUserId })).UserGroupIds;
    return (from documentType in entitySet
            join documentTypePermission in Repository.DocumentTypePermissions on documentType.Id equals documentTypePermission.DocumentTypeId
            join userSelectionParam in Repository.UserSelectionParams on documentTypePermission.UserSelectionId equals userSelectionParam.Id
            join userGroupId in Repository.ConvertToBigIntTable(userGroupIds, "userGroupId")
            on userSelectionParam.UserGroupId equals userGroupId.Id into UserGroupIds
            from userGroupId in UserGroupIds.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where documentTypePermission.IsActive && ((userSelectionParam.UserGroupId != null && userGroupId.Id != null)
                                                        || (userSelectionParam.UserId != null && userSelectionParam.UserId == CurrentUserId))
            select documentTypePermission);
}
```

**Generated Expression:**

```cs
DbSet<EDocumentType>()
    .Join(
        inner: DbSet<EDocumentTypePermission>(), 
        outerKeySelector: documentType => (long?)documentType.Id, 
        innerKeySelector: documentTypePermission => documentTypePermission.DocumentTypeId, 
        resultSelector: (documentType, documentTypePermission) => new { 
            documentType = documentType, 
            documentTypePermission = documentTypePermission
         })
    .Join(
        inner: DbSet<EUserSelectionParam>(), 
        outerKeySelector: <>h__TransparentIdentifier0 => <>h__TransparentIdentifier0.documentTypePermission.UserSelectionId, 
        innerKeySelector: userSelectionParam => (long?)userSelectionParam.Id, 
        resultSelector: (<>h__TransparentIdentifier0, userSelectionParam) => new { 
            <>h__TransparentIdentifier0 = <>h__TransparentIdentifier0, 
            userSelectionParam = userSelectionParam
         })
    .GroupJoin(
        inner: BananaContext.ConvertCSVToBigIntTable(
            List: <>c__DisplayClass958_0.List, 
            Delim: <>c__DisplayClass958_0.Delim), 
        outerKeySelector: <>h__TransparentIdentifier1 => <>h__TransparentIdentifier1.userSelectionParam.UserGroupId, 
        innerKeySelector: userGroupId => (long?)userGroupId.Id, 
        resultSelector: (<>h__TransparentIdentifier1, UserGroupIds) => new { 
            <>h__TransparentIdentifier1 = <>h__TransparentIdentifier1, 
            UserGroupIds = UserGroupIds
         })
    .SelectMany(
        collectionSelector: <>h__TransparentIdentifier2 => <>h__TransparentIdentifier2.UserGroupIds
            .DefaultIfEmpty(), 
        resultSelector: (<>h__TransparentIdentifier2, userGroupId) => new { 
            <>h__TransparentIdentifier2 = <>h__TransparentIdentifier2, 
            userGroupId = userGroupId
         })
    .Where(<>h__TransparentIdentifier3 => <>h__TransparentIdentifier3.<>h__TransparentIdentifier2.<>h__TransparentIdentifier1.<>h__TransparentIdentifier0.documentTypePermission.IsActive && <>h__TransparentIdentifier3.<>h__TransparentIdentifier2.<>h__TransparentIdentifier1.userSelectionParam.UserGroupId != null && (long?)<>h__TransparentIdentifier3.userGroupId.Id != null || <>h__TransparentIdentifier3.<>h__TransparentIdentifier2.<>h__TransparentIdentifier1.userSelectionParam.UserId != null && <>h__TransparentIdentifier3.<>h__TransparentIdentifier2.<>h__TransparentIdentifier1.userSelectionParam.UserId == (long?)AbstractDomainBehavior.CurrentUserId)
    .Select(<>h__TransparentIdentifier3 => <>h__TransparentIdentifier3.<>h__TransparentIdentifier2.<>h__TransparentIdentifier1.<>h__TransparentIdentifier0.documentTypePermission)
```

**Generated SQL:**

```sql
DECLARE @__List_1 nvarchar(4000) = N'1,5,6,7,8,14,15,44,46,62,63,64,67,69,73,85,88';
DECLARE @__Delim_2 nvarchar(1) = N',';
DECLARE @__CurrentUserId_3 bigint = CAST(1 AS bigint);

SELECT [d0].[Id], [d0].[Condition], [d0].[CreatedById], [d0].[CreatedTime], [d0].[DocumentTypeId], [d0].[IsActive], [d0].[IsOverridable], [d0].[IsReevaluate], [d0].[RowVersion], [d0].[UpdatedById], [d0].[UpdatedTime], [d0].[UserSelectionId], [d0].[AssignmentType], [d0].[ConditionFor], [d0].[CreationAllowed], [d0].[Permission]
FROM [DocumentTypes] AS [d]
INNER JOIN [DocumentTypePermissions] AS [d0] ON [d].[Id] = [d0].[DocumentTypeId]
INNER JOIN [UserSelectionParams] AS [u] ON [d0].[UserSelectionId] = [u].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ConvertCSVToBigIntTable](@__List_1, @__Delim_2) AS [c] ON [u].[UserGroupId] = [c].[Id]
WHERE ([d0].[IsActive] = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND (([u].[UserGroupId] IS NOT NULL AND [c].[Id] IS NOT NULL) OR ([u].[UserId] IS NOT NULL AND ([u].[UserId] = @__CurrentUserId_3)))
```

```
EF Core version: 6.0.1
Database provider:  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Target framework: .NET 6.0
Operating system: Win 10 Pro
IDE: Visual Studio 2022 v17.0.4
```

UPDATE: One more peculiar case: Instead of using generic object "entitySet" if I then use direct DbContext.DbSet reference, then all the errors go away and the Sql gets generated correctly:

````
 private IQueryable<IDocumentTypePermission> GetDocumentTypePermissionsTest<T>(IQueryable<T> entitySet) where T : class, IDocumentType
        {
            var userGroupIds = RunComponent(GetActiveUserGroupsOfCurrentUser.New(new GetActiveUserGroupsOfCurrentUserParam() { CurrentUserId = CurrentUserId })).UserGroupIds;
            return (from documentType in Repository.GetDbContext().DocumentTypes
                    join userGroupId in Repository.ConvertToBigIntTable(userGroupIds, "userGroupId")
                    on documentType.Id equals userGroupId.Id into UserGroupIds
                    from userGroupId in UserGroupIds.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join documentTypePermission in Repository.DocumentTypePermissions
                    on documentType.Id equals documentTypePermission.DocumentTypeId
                    join userSelectionParam in Repository.UserSelectionParams
                    on documentTypePermission.UserSelectionId equals userSelectionParam.Id


                    where documentTypePermission.IsActive && ((userSelectionParam.UserGroupId != null && userGroupId.Id != null)
                                                              || (userSelectionParam.UserId != null && userSelectionParam.UserId == CurrentUserId))
                    select documentTypePermission);
        }
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `GroupJoin` with `SelectMany`

```cs
var query = 
    from documentType in entitySet
    from userGroupId in Repository.ConvertToBigIntTable(userGroupIds, "userGroupId")
        .Where(userGroupId => documentType.Id == userGroupId.Id)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    join documentTypePermission in Repository.DocumentTypePermissions
        on documentType.Id equals documentTypePermission.DocumentTypeId
    join userSelectionParam in Repository.UserSelectionParams
        on documentTypePermission.UserSelectionId equals userSelectionParam.Id

    ....
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @Svyatoslav, it does seem to work.
But this means that I have to replace so many LINQ in my project and that leads to the question as to how the same LINQ is working perfectly fine on LinqPad7 (Targeting EFCore 6 and .NET6), any ideas?

Comment: Even that I know how to build LINQ Translator - EF Core translator is something... complicated. Do not replace everything, probably they have failed with TableValued functions.

Comment: So essentially you are saying that LinqPad is not directly using EFCore libraries but adding some more magic to make it work?
I understand your point on probably the EFCore team has missed implementing TableValuedFunction on GroupJoins, I did have opened a ticket to check their response and have also added the solution that you gave.
[link](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27343

Comment: LINQPad do not use magic. Probably you have use different EF Core versions or something else which changes parsing behavior.

Comment: Updated the question, with another case which uses direct DbContext reference and the old query seems to work (obviously not the desired code that I want, but wonder why such very weird behavior)

Comment: Well, they are marked this as a bug and it looks like a bug. I have just proposed alternative LEFT join defining which has different LINQ translation algorithm.